# railsでpublicフォルダのファイルをレンダリングする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsでpublicフォルダのファイルをレンダリングする方法を教えて下さい。

`public/stylesheets/hoge.css`

このファイルの中身をそのままビューの一部として展開したいのですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/stylesheets/hoge.css" %>
```

上記のように書けば任意のファイルを挿入できますが、特に理由が無ければHTMLに直接CSSを埋め込まずに

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "hoge", :media => "all" %>
```

とでもした方が良さそうです。